# AXI lite tlast port missing reason

Tags: bus, soc

Why in AXI lite protocol there is no tlast port?

Mainly AXI lite consists of AXI-stream protocols, but there is no tlast port in AXI lite.
Can someone justify what was the reason of not including the tlast port in AXI-lite.

Answer (score 1):

xLAST in axi is for indicating the last transfer, but in AXI-light all transaction contain single transfer(all transactions are of burst length 1 AXI_spec_B1.1), so AXI-light not require xLAST signal.

correct me if i am wrong.
-Dhaval Sanepara